# Getting webpage pictures to overlap scroll

Tags: html, image, css, background

I'm doing the [Free Code Camp](http://www.freecodecamp.com/) thing and the first Zipline challenge is to replicate the following webpage on [Code Pen](http://codepen.io/ThiagoFerreir4/full/eNMxEp/). What I'm looking for is a hint or two in the right direction so I can get the pictures to scroll like they do on the webpage. I don't want the answer(s), just a hint or hints in the right direction so that I can do my own work. I think I'm suppose to use CSS, and if that's the case I have no idea which property/properties to use, maybe one of the `background` properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the hint I was looking for is 'css parallax scrolling'. Thanks for all the help.